# Importar datos de archivo csv

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, sql-server-2014

Tengo un archivo csv el cual tiene estos datos que los saque de un solo campo.

[image: csv]

Como verán no solo es datos de un solo campo.

En la tabla donde quiero insertar estos datos tiene la siguiente estructura.
[image: sql]

La información que quiero ingresar esta en la cuarta posición, ¿de que manera puedo conseguir ponerle campos vacíos separados por comas de tal manera que llegue a la posición deseada?

Los datos lo obtengo mediante esta consulta de una base de datos PostgreSql

```
COPY (SELECT descripcion FROM tblarticulos) TO 'D:\\productos.csv' DELIMITER ',';
```

Y los datos de ese archivo csv los voy a insertar en una base de datos SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si querés generar un archivo con 3 campos vacíos adelante de la descripción usando ese query reemplaza el select por:

```
select null, null, null, descripcion from tblarticulos
```

Comment: ¿Y si al ultimo campo estado le quiero poner 1, como puedo hacer? ya que no puede ir vacío.

Comment: Pues entiendo que igual: select null, null, null, descripcion, null, null, null, 1 from tblarticulos

Comment: ProductoId es un campo int identity sin embargo me da el siguiente error: Error de conversión de datos de carga masiva (tipo no coincidente o carácter no válido para la página de códigos especificada) en la fila 1, columna 1 (ProductoId).

Comment: Cual es la definición del campo? Es un id, probablemente sea not null, en ese caso o le cambias los null al id correcto antes de importar el archivo, o lo importar a una tabla nueva sin restricciones. Reemplazas ahi los null por los id correctos, y luego haces un insert select desde la tabla nueva a la tabla de productos. Y finalmente eliminar la tabla de más que se uso para importar los datos.